# PHP: simplified sql resultset, no garbage

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to simply harvest a sql resultset via PHP without the added key => value pairs that I love so much. >_<

the code below is able to grab values out of the key value pairs but gives me it twice in a row.

```
        $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=???', $user, $pass);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM products";
        foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $results)
        {
            foreach($results as $key => $value){
                echo $value.';';
            }
        }
```

results: "what;what;im;im;looking;looking;for;for;".

I know I am missing something very basic and it would be VITAL if that could be cleared up...I have tried modifying this time and time again and this is the closest I can get to the REAL desired output.

desired results: "what;im;looking;for;".

Comment: replace the first foreach with $results = $dbh->query($sql)

Comment: It sounds like `PDO:query()` returns both `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` and `PDO::FETCH_NUM`. So try adding it as 2nd param -> `$dbh->query($sql, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`

Comment: You were right, Sean! Thank you! this has been driving me crazy, lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PDO most likely returns both column names and ordinal positions as the `$key` in your map.  You can filter the output by checking whether they key `is_numeric` and only return the values that corresponding to the ordinal values.

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=???', $user, $pass);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products";
foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $results)
{
    foreach($results as $key => $value){
        if (is_numeric($key)) {
            echo $value.';';
        }
    }
}
```

As @Sean mentions, you can return exclusively the column names (or ordinal positions) by passing an appropriate value into the second parameter of the `query` function call:

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=???', $user, $pass);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM products";
foreach ($dbh->query($sql, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $results)
{
    foreach($results as $key => $value){
        echo $value.';';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of other developers and myself I would like to finalize the code into barebones for readability to be learned or manipulated more easily by others. THANKS FOR THE HELP, GUYS!!!

```
$dsn='mysql:host=localhost;dbname=YOUR_DATABASE';
$user='USER_NAME';
$pass='PASSWORD';

$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass);

foreach ($dbh->query("SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE", PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) as $results){
    foreach($results as $key => $value){
        echo $value;
    }
}
```